# Query works but stored procedure gives me a formatting Error

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, formatting

Query returns exactly what I want but when I plug the same structure into my stored Procedure I get a formatting error.

Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure RegisterUser, Line 21
Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function.

Here's my query.

```
DECLARE @Department int
SET @Department = (SELECT DepartmentLink FROM DepartmentMaster WHERE Name = 
'Inventory')

DECLARE @Position int
SET @Position = (SELECT TypeLink FROM EmployeeTypes Where Title = 'Clerk')

DECLARE @UID int
set @UID = (SELECT ID FROM EmployeeMaster WHERE FirstName = 'John' and 
LastName = 'Doe')

(SELECT convert(varchar,FORMAT (@Department,'00#'))+'-'+ 
convert(varchar,FORMAT(@Position, '0#'))+'-
'+convert(varchar,FORMAT(@UID,'000#')) as EmployeeID)
```

Here's my Stored Procedure..

```
CREATE Procedure RegisterUser
(
@FirstName varchar(255),
@LastName varchar(255),
@Department varchar(255),
@Email varchar(255),
@Password varchar(255),
@UserType varchar(255),
@EmployeeID varchar(255),
@DepartmentLink int,
@Position int,
@UID int
)
AS

SET @Department = (SELECT DepartmentLink FROM DepartmentMaster WHERE Name = 
@Department)

SET @Position = (SELECT TypeLink FROM EmployeeTypes Where Title = @UserType)

set @UID = (SELECT ID FROM EmployeeMaster WHERE FirstName = @FirstName and 
LastName = @LastName)

SET @EmployeeID = (SELECT convert(varchar,FORMAT (@Department,'00#'))+'-'+ 
convert(varchar,FORMAT(@Position, '0#'))+'-
'+convert(varchar,FORMAT(@UID,'000#')) as EmployeeID)

INSERT INTO EmployeeMaster(FirstName, LastName, Department, 
Email,Password,CreationDate, EmployeeID, Active)
VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, (SELECT DepartmentLink FROM DepartmentMaster 
WHERE Name = @Department), @Email, @Password, GETDATE(),
@EmployeeID
,1)
```

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using (presumably SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing this as:

```
CREATE Procedure RegisterUser (
    @FirstName varchar(255),
    @LastName varchar(255),
    @Department varchar(255),
    @Email varchar(255),
    @Password varchar(255),
    @UserType varchar(255),
    @EmployeeID varchar(255),
    @DepartmentLink int,
    @Position int,
    @UID int
) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DepartmentLink varchar(255);
    DECLARE @PositionLink int;
    DECLARE @Uid_new int;
    DECLARE @EmployeeId_new varchar(255);

    SELECT @DepartmentLink = DepartmentLink
    FROM DepartmentMaster
    WHERE Name = @Department;

    SELECT @PostiionLink = TypeLink
    FROM EmployeeTypes 
    WHERE Title = @UserType;

    SELECT @Uid_new = ID
    FROM EmployeeMaster
    WHERE FirstName = @FirstName and LastName = @LastName;

    SELECT @EmployeeID_new = (FORMAT(@Department, '00#') + '-' + 
                              FORMAT(@Position, '0#')) + '-' + 
                              FORMAT(@UID, '000#')
                             );

    INSERT INTO EmployeeMaster(FirstName, LastName, Department, Email, Password, CreationDate, EmployeeID, Active)
        VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName,
               @DepartmentLink, @Email, @Password, GETDATE(),
               @EmployeeID_new, 1
              );
END;  -- RegisterUser
```

You could simplify this further.

Notes:

- Your code needs a `BEGIN`/`END`
- Don't assign values to parameters, unless they are output parameters.  Instead, use local variables.
- `FORMAT()` already returning a string -- no need for another conversion.
- `SET` with a subquery just looks awkward to me, when you can do the assignment with a `SELECT`.
- I don't think you need all the arguments, but that is another matter.